# How to create a .log file sequence with a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I need some help, I need to create a sequence of files. Ex. 1.log 2.log 3.log 4.log and so on, detail I need to define the initial value and the final value there it creates for me inside the desired folder. Below is the code more or less with the idea I want, the file is called inuti.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e " ENTER INITIAL NUMBER: "
read num1

echo -e " ENTER THE FINAL NUMBER NOW: ";
read num2

#num3 = num1
#num4 = num2
cd /var/actus/digital/nfce/inutilizar/
touch {$num1..$num2}.log
ls /var/actus/digital/nfce/inutilizar/
```

is generating an exemple file as if it had defined 1 and 2, it is generating {1..2} .log and I need to generate 1.log and 2.log

Comment: If you are looking for the usual behavior of system logs, it's quite a bit more complex and incrementing numbers go *back* in time, not forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seq` utility which can print consecutive numbers:

```
touch $(seq -f "%5.0f.log" $num1 $num2)
```

If the number of digits is more than 5 you can increase the value inside

BTW will be much easy if you change the first line of your script from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and keep the rest. IMHO this expression (with curly brackets) do not work in Bourne Shell.

Comment: That might work for limited purposes and it is possible limited purposes are all the asker needs.  But if the asker is expecting something like usual system log behavior this is going to be missing what an actual log rotation does, the numbers will be backwards with respect to time, it won't compress older files or eventually delete them, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, all this is correct. But from the OP question I do not see anything about log rotation, compression, etc

Answer (score 0):

The valid form of *`brace expansion`* requires integers to be present inside the brackets. 
When you run your script, only integer substitution takes place which converts `{$num1..$num2}` to, for example, `{1..2}`. For this correct form to be further processed, use the **`eval`** command :

```
eval touch {$num1..$num2}.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
    read -p "enter value " n1
    read -p "enter value " n2
    cd /home/runner/unixshell1
    eval touch {$n1..$n2}.txt
    echo "files are created"
    ls -ltr
```

Using eval only we will generate files otherwise it will give out like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner    0 Jul 30 05:53 {1..3}.txt
```

**using eval files will be created  from 1 to 3**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner    0 Jul 30 05:49 3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner    0 Jul 30 05:49 2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner runner    0 Jul 30 05:49 1.txt
```